# Delete button in recyclerview is not positioned properly in some cards android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have to delete images from recyclerview, so for that, I'm added one delete button at the top right corner of the cardview. But in some cards that delete button is positioned properly and in some cards it is not.

Here is my XML file code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/android"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageview"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageview" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Below is the output

Here delete button is not displayed properly in the top three cards but it is displayed properly at bottom cards
[image]

It is also displayed properly in portrait mode:
[image]

Please tell me what I have to do in order to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner ConstraintLayout has

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Should be

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

See if this helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageview"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageview" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```